# Google OAuth revoke access token by scopes

Tags: oauth, google-analytics, oauth-2.0, gmail, google-api-python-client

We dealing with Google Authentications scopes, and we facing an issue on revocation.

1 - We have user authorized his **Google Analytics** account

2 - Then later on he can add his **GMAIL** account
The two steps above can be switched

3 - Now if we want to revoke the access, Both of the authorizations are revoked

We went through google documentation many times, couldn't find out where to revoke the token based on the scope

What we want to do is to allow users to choose which Google App's token to revoke

- User choose to remove **Google Analytics** token or **GMAIL** token

Has someone ever faced and found a way to do such a thing ?

Comment: Yes, you can't revoke tokens by scope unfortunately. The entire app is revoked, no matter how many scopes you have connected and what `refresh_token` you used for revoke. It will simply revoke everything. Thats a really silly thing since oAuth flows are different for each scope, therefore revocation should also be separated.

Comment: @AndreiStalbe yes, I had to revoke everything and re-auth again, that's not really clever from Google :(